# RegEx Remove "-" but not " - " from a string

Tags: regex

I want to remove "-" but not " - " from a string.
For Example: "01-Frozen - Madonna.mp3" becomes "01Frozen - Madonna.mp3"
I will than remove all digits using /d, I have seen some patterns for it.
So can any body help?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: If all you are doing is removing an exact substring, you don't need regex. Most languages will have a replace method. Use that.

Comment: It really depends on the language here. For example in JavaScript, you could do `string.replace(/(^|\S)-(\S|$)/g,'$1$2')`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about regular expression, totally depends on the tool or language, and still doesn't include the required complementary tag.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the example you already specified. `01-Frozen - Madonna.mp3`.

The pattern is this: `<non space character><hyphen><non space character>`

If you need a space, the regex would be `\s` which will match a single non breaking space. The wonderful aspect of Regular Expression is that most match flags have an opposite, usually denoted by a capital letter of the same identifier. Since, in this case, we *don't* want a space, we could use `\S` which matches all characters that are not a space.

So the pattern now looks like: `\S-\S`.

If you've tried this, it won't work as expected since we want *only* the hyphens that do not have non-space-items around them and should not include the non-space-items themselves.

Cases like these call for a special kind of...erm...things termed as `lookaheads` and `lookbehinds`. Usually this involves a question mark and one more identifier — one of `>`, `<`, `=`, `:`, `!`. These extra identifiers ensure what kind of lazy you want your matches to get. You can read more about them [here](http://jieyanghu.com/2011/03/01/regex-lookahead-and-lookbehind/).

<s>For this case, we need to use the `=` which will ensure that token appended to it — `\S` in our case — won't be a part of the result. This is called a `positive lookahead` matcher. So the final regex looks like this:</s>

```
/(?=\S)-(?=\S)/
```

[Edited]

Paraphrasing @jerry's comments:

> Well, if you want it to work properly, you'll need a lookbehind: /(?<=\S)-(?=\S)/. Though I would prefer negative ones in this case as it would be more natural to say 'not preceded by' and 'not followed by': /(?

Option 1:

```
/(?<=\S)-(?=\S)/
```

Option 2:

```
/(?<!\s)-(?!\s)/
```

Comment: [That doesn't always work by the way](http://regex101.com/r/lA4zH1)...

Comment: True. It works for the exact case pointed out in the question, though. It doesn't specify anything about the other cases. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Well, if you want it to work properly, you'll need a *lookbehind*: `/(?<=\S)-(?=\S)/`. Though I would prefer negative ones in this case as it would be more natural to say 'not preceded by' and 'not followed by': `/(?<!\s)-(?!\s)/`.

Comment: Updating this. Makes more sense.